Force website (add to homepage) to open as an app instead of in Safari
You can add websites to home page. However some (most) websites don't add this tag <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"   />  so it opens up in Safari instead. I don't want this behavior. How can I change it?
One possible solution might be using a MITM proxy to insert this tag, but I'm not sure if I would only need to do this once and iOS will "remember" if the website can be opened in a separate window, or will I need to do this every time.
